# Copy multiple files from sub folder into one folder

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I have folder that has subfolders each with many different files.
I'd like to copy all of the files (not subdirectories) into one folder

```
import os
import shutil

src = r'C:\TEMP\dir'
dest = r'C:\TEMP\new'

src_files = os.listdir(src)
for file_name in src_files:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
    if (os.path.isfile(full_file_name)):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, dest)
```

when I run the code, there is no error but no files is copied either.
I do not know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I don't think python has a simple way of doing it. Knowing how "deep" the folder is very important for your solution, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @LampPost in my case, the depth is no more than 4.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
import os
import shutil

src = r'C:\TEMP\dir'
dest = r'C:\TEMP\new'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)
        shutil.copy2(filename, dest)
```